# Android, my app won't accept my self signed ssl cert

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

I have a self signed ssl cert for my local tomcat application and I'm trying to connect to the tomcat web app from my android using https but I'm getting this error:

java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

This is a common problem but there are issues with all the solutions I have found so far. A lot of them just create a method to accept all ssl certs which defeats the points of using ssl. Another problem with the solutions is that they all use apache httpclient which is deprecated and I want to use urlconnection.

I have a keystore.bks in res/raw, how do I get my android app to accept this cert?

This is the code I'm using to connect to my tomcat application:

```
URL url = new URL("https://192.168.0.6:8443/Rest/android/login");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should register a [`KeyStore`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html) using a [`TrustManagerFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/TrustManagerFactory.html). See http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html